# Rename Folders after first file inside that folder using OSX Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a bunch of folders that all have the same name or iterating numbers...like Material 01, Material 02, Material 181 etc.
Inside there are lots of videofiles who got the right name. I need to rename the folder to have the same name as the first file inside that folder (sorted by name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac terminal is usually using bash, so something like that should do the trick:
Inside your directory where you have your folders: Put that in a file called rename.sh and then type `bash rename.sh` and hit enter:

```
#! /bin/bash

for dir in Material*; do

  while read -rd ''; do
    newname=$(basename -- "${REPLY%.*}")
    break
  done < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.*' -type f -print0 | sort -z)

  echo "dir:${dir} new:${newname}"
  mv -n "$dir" "$newname"
done
```

Assuming that:

- every first video has a different filename
- that by first you mean the alphabetically first.

**Note:** The folder will be named according to the filename without its extension. But if you'd like to add also the extension to the new name of the folder, you can substitute the first line in the while-loop by `newname=$(basename -- "$REPLY")`

This solution also ignores hidden files using `-not -name '.*'`, and is able to handle filenames including newlines. But in my opinion, it is generally a bad idea to use newlines in filenames.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196411/discussion-between-avermaet-and-robc).

Comment: Thx its perfectly fine like this now

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

```
ername = $_SESSION['id'];

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);

$location = "your_location/$username/$rand_dir_name";

mv($location);
```

Comment: What is this and how is the OP supposed to use it?

Comment: this is a shell scripting file you can make a file like a rename_directory.sh then make it executable then run it from your terminal

Comment: @TechDevils - ... then it fails. Please edit your answer to show what the content of the `rename_directory.sh` should be, and ensure you validate your code via [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) prior to posting. I also suggest that you carefully read the question again to better understand the OP's actual requirement. Currently the code provided in your answer looks like PHP for some other arbitrary requirement.